# I have five tables and i want to eloquent ORM relationship in laravel. and retrieve the value using controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Tables:**

users Table: id, first_name, last_name, zip_id

---

zips Table: id, zip, city_id

---

cities Table: id, city, state_id

---

states Table: id, state, country_id

---

countries Table: id, country, city_id

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships). Then apply the appropriate relationships. 
For example, between `users` and `zips` table there should be a relationship. A specific zip 'has many' users and on the other hand a user 'belongs to' only one zip.

You can translate this idea into code.

In your zip model you can define a function like

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
```

In your user model you can define

```
 public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Zip');
    }
```

In this way you can define all the relations.

Comment: $user = $this->user->with('zip','city')->get(); 
"Call to undefined relationship [city] on model [App\User]." 
I am unable to get city data.

Comment: @RajGoldar This answer isn't giving you all of the relationships, it's giving you an example of how to apply those relationships. You will need to add the rests of the relationships yourself.

Comment: $user = $this->user->with('zip','city')->get();
i want to get user, zip and city data what will be the syntax in controller.
i was trying above syntax and received this error
 "Call to undefined relationship [city] on model [App\User]."